# How do we handle different level of agreement bias in surveys

Tags: survey, bias

For instance say you are running a survey (to get a rating between 1-5 for your product) over demographic A and demographic B.
Users in A tend to respond with lower ratings and users in B tend to respond with higher ratings. You are fairly confident that the product is doing similarly in both demographics and the higher ratings by B are indicative of bias rather than the product being better for users in B.
How do we handle this? Sampling bias and non-response bias can be handled by upweighting or downweighting some of the data but that won't help here?

Comment: How do you know that the product is doing similarly in the two groups?

Comment: We're fairly certain. There might be some differences but not as extreme as in the data we're seeing.

Comment: OK. What's your goal ultimately? Predicting sales based on ratings? Something else?

Comment: Not exactly. The product is actually recommending multiple different items to users and we want to use the ratings to predict if an item should be shown to a user or not.